# HIVE - Manual parse data enclosed by double quotes and separated by comma

Tags: csv, parsing, hadoop, split, hive

I've seen some similar questions but since the problem is not exactly the same or then solutions do not apply in my case, I post my issue here.

I am parsing a table that contains a csv rows in a `csv_line` column.
The issue is that some columns have commas`,` which is also the field separator. Those columns are embedded in quotes.

The parsing I was doing is:

```
with  
sample as (
select 'field1,field3,"http://another.domain/abc/...eIds=111,222,333,444,...,",CustomerX,end' as csv_line)

select 

 regexp_extract(csv_line,'(,?(".*?"|[^,]*)){1}') as f1
 regexp_extract(csv_line,'(,?(".*?"|[^,]*)){n}') as fn

from raw_sample
```

I have tried to replace characters/commas.

I know that *OpenCSVSerde* allows to define the separator character and escape double-quotes, in the Create table, but I am looking perhaps to a property that can be set, or perhaps a regular expression, that can do the split in the correct way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "manual parsing"? Why not using CSV SerDe?

Comment: manual parsing, doing it in hive. I need to compute several csv files and merge tham in one single table. Besides other calculations. I need the query to perform the job. :/ Perhaps I need to do this with Spark..

Comment: So again, why not using CSV SerDe?

Comment: How can I use it, without being in the create table statement?

Comment: Not clear. Please give an data sample that reflects the actual scenario including the required results.

Comment: I updated my post. hope it's clear. Thanks for trying.

Comment: I gave what you have requested but It is still very unclear (you are not describing the data structure you currently have) and there is a good chance there is much easier solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with raw_sample as (
select 'field1,field2,fiend3,123,456,"http://some.domain/abc/Player.aspx?playerID=111&BrowseIds=2221,423062611,423870887,424044345,...,",THIS_IS_MY,en,20 294 998 1001,end' as raw_line
)

select  regexp_extract(raw_line,'(,?(".*?"|[^,]*)){01}',2) as c01
       ,regexp_extract(raw_line,'(,?(".*?"|[^,]*)){02}',2) as c02
       ,regexp_extract(raw_line,'(,?(".*?"|[^,]*)){03}',2) as c03
       ,regexp_extract(raw_line,'(,?(".*?"|[^,]*)){04}',2) as c04
       ,regexp_extract(raw_line,'(,?(".*?"|[^,]*)){05}',2) as c05
       ,regexp_extract(raw_line,'(,?(".*?"|[^,]*)){06}',2) as c06
       ,regexp_extract(raw_line,'(,?(".*?"|[^,]*)){07}',2) as c07
       ,regexp_extract(raw_line,'(,?(".*?"|[^,]*)){08}',2) as c08
       ,regexp_extract(raw_line,'(,?(".*?"|[^,]*)){09}',2) as c09
       ,regexp_extract(raw_line,'(,?(".*?"|[^,]*)){10}',2) as c10

from    raw_sample
;
```

---

```
+--------+--------+--------+-----+-----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+-----+-----------------+-----+
|  c01   |  c02   |  c03   | c04 | c05 |                                                 c06                                                 |    c07     | c08 |       c09       | c10 |
+--------+--------+--------+-----+-----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+-----+-----------------+-----+
| field1 | field2 | fiend3 | 123 | 456 | "http://some.domain/abc/Player.aspx?playerID=111&BrowseIds=2221,423062611,423870887,424044345,...," | THIS_IS_MY | en  | 20 294 998 1001 | end |
+--------+--------+--------+-----+-----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+-----+-----------------+-----+
```

Comment: That works, nice regex, and many thanks. Data structure is a bit complex. At least this seems to work well so far :)

Comment: given the regex you mentioned, would it be possible to create an array (using split) what will hold on each index a different group? this way it would be faster to run the query, since the regex will run once and then data could be retrieved from the array.